# Excel 2010 "sending the command to the program" error

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, windows-server-2008-r2

Multiple domain users receive the following Excel 2010 (32-bit edition) error occasionally when opening random XLS files.

> There was a problem sending the command to the program

https://i.stack.imgur.com/znyQK.jpg

Files are located on a Server 2008 R2 SMB share. Domain users have Full Control permissions access.

Excel 2010 (32-bit edition) is on a Server 2008 R2 terminal server.

Sometimes a file that gets the error will open ok the next time.

I have tried setting Excel to run in "XP SP3" compatibility mode for all users, and have ensured that "Ignore other applications that use DDE" in Excel options.

Any ideas on how to resolve this one?

Answer (score 1):

Typically this is caused by Excel's OLE timeout, which cannot be extended.

To avoid this, I always leave one window of Excel open.  Then if you launch any Excel file from another source (e.g. Windows Explorer, File Share, Website), it will open into that existing Excel window.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a gneerally applicable solution. I use Excel twice a day, once in the morning right after arriving in the office, and once in the evening before leaving work, because my time spreadsheet is based on Excel. Hence, I open the current year's time spreadsheet right after booting (which is when the described error strikes *almost* every day - been observing this for 4 years now), so "leaving one window of Excel open" would not be a solution there. Also, as I don't use Excel at all during my work, having Excel open all day seems like a waste of resources and taskbar space.